# Plotting non date-formatted time-series in Grafana

Tags: python, postgresql, grafana

I'm trying to plot a time-series in grafana but my date-column is just an integral value, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc. instead of an actual date-formatted column. How can I use this column as a date column in a graph panel?

My SQL looks like this:

```
select date_index as "date", value from my_table, order by date_index;
```

It currently just plots one value (the last one I think) and then says “data points outside time range”.

Comment: If you don't care about real time values you can just set time range in Grafana to start on Jan 1,1970.

Comment: How do I do this? I seem to only be able to change "Last" and "Amount" under the "Time range" tab

Comment: I ment global dashboard time range setting (top-right dropdown in Grafana page), not panel time range.